# Export multiple files to raster using rioxarray in Python

Tags: raster, python-xarray, netcdf4

The following code opens a text file which has monthly data starting in the year 2000 to 2022 in the format "GLDAS_NOAH025_M.A202201.021.nc4", which represents one single file.

I can successfully export one file from the dataset to a single raster file, however, I'm trying to export multiple files to format tiff, naming the files following the format previously stated changing the date, for example "GLDAS_NOAH025_M.**A202201**.021.tiff", "GLDAS_NOAH025_M.A**202112**.021.tiff", etc. , which is my attempt in the last 2 lines of code, but I can only export a single tiff file. Any idea of how I can export every file? Thanks in advance.

```
archivo=open("subset_GLDAS_NOAH025_M_2.1_20220419_020445.txt")
for linea in archivo:
    linea=linea.rstrip()
    url=re.findall('^https\S*nc4$',linea)
    url=' '.join(url)
    #url=str("'"+url+"'")
    url=str(url)
    print(url)
    filename = url[url.rfind('/')+1:]  

    ncfile = xr.open_dataset(filename,engine='netcdf4')

    pr = ncfile["PotEvap_tavg"]
    prec=pr.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim='lon', y_dim='lat')
    pr.rio.crs
    pr.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)
    name=[]
    name.append(re.findall('^GLDAS\S[0-9.]*.021.nc4$', linea))
   
    with xr.open_dataset(filename,engine='netcdf4'):
        pr.rio.to_raster(r"PotEvap_tavg_raster"+str(name)+".tiff")
```

Comment: can you put it in a loop? sorry I'm confused by your question. what are you iterating over and how should `pr` and the filepath differ for each file? can you show us what your data looks like (e.g. paste the result of `print(pr)` as a code block) and what's happening in name? also - I think you should probably use `name.extend` rather than `.append` since `re.findall` returns a list

Comment: pr is a parameter that I need from the dataset, which I managed to get properly; unfortunately I can't paste the entire result because it's too long. The code exports multiple files in format nc4 (that also works ok) and what I'm looking for is to create a tiff file from each one of the previous nc4 files using rioxarray.to_raster, each one called "PotEvap_tavg_rasterYYYYMM.tiff" but I can only create one and is called "PotEvap_tavg_raster[].tiff".

Comment: that's because your regular expression `'^GLDAS\S[0-9.]*.021.nc4$'` is failing to match whatever is inside your text file. I'm not sure how to help with that without more information.